# Remove a div from html template in TYPO3

Tags: html, typo3-8.x

I need to remove the outer div from the following template

```
<div id="c6" class="frame frame-default frame-type-fluidcontent_content frame-layout-0">
   <div>............</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is on the fluid_styled_content extension. Coming from the Layout "Default".

You can find the file here: \typo3\sysext\fluid_styled_content\Resources\Private\Layouts\Default.html

```
<f:if condition="{data.frame_class} != none">
        <f:then>

            <div id="c{data.uid}" class="frame frame-{data.frame_class} frame-type-{data.CType} frame-layout-{data.layout}{f:if(condition: data.space_before_class, then: ' frame-space-before-{data.space_before_class}')}{f:if(condition: data.space_after_class, then: ' frame-space-after-{data.space_after_class}')}">
                <f:if condition="{data._LOCALIZED_UID}">
                    <a id="c{data._LOCALIZED_UID}"></a>
                </f:if>
                <f:render section="Before" optional="true">
                    <f:render partial="DropIn/Before/All" arguments="{_all}" />
                </f:render>
                <f:render section="Header" optional="true">
                    <f:render partial="Header/All" arguments="{_all}" />
                </f:render>
                <f:render section="Main" optional="true" />
                <f:render section="Footer" optional="true">
                    <f:render partial="Footer/All" arguments="{_all}" />
                </f:render>
                <f:render section="After" optional="true">
                    <f:render partial="DropIn/After/All" arguments="{_all}" />
                </f:render>
            </div>

        </f:then>
```

How to change it?

You can copy the file put it into your sitepackage extension or even into the fileadmin (not recommended!).

You can simply remove the div what you don't need in the copied variant.

Then you can change the following **constant** in TypoScript template:

```
styles.templates.layoutRootPath = <your_path>
```

Fore example If you have an extension:

```
styles.templates.layoutRootPath = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Layouts
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to overtire the fluid template file. Use below typoscript for overtire template file.

```
lib.fluidContent {
   templateRootPaths {
      200 = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Templates/
   }
   partialRootPaths {
      200 = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Partials/
   }
   layoutRootPaths {
      200 = EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Layouts/
   }
}
```

Now, you need to copy the original `Layout.html(typo3\sysext\fluid_styled_content\Resources\Private\Layouts\Default.html)` file and put in your extensionpath and do change in this file as per your requirements.